# What's the best practice for saving initial data in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

I'm working on a project where some entities are supposed to contain initial data that should be set up when the application is started for the first time.

As of now, we have a function executing when a service is used and if the corresponding entity is empty. But this forces us to check this entity with an `if` statement everytime the service is called. It was supposed to be a temporary solution.

Now I'm wondering what could be the best way to save that initial data. Is it by using an insertion query that would be executed after setting up the database with all its tables structure (in master.xml for example) ? If so, how can we make sure the data won't be inserted again after restarting the application ? Or is the best way still using the entity services, but then how to do it effectively ?

Comment: Yes, we do use JPA.

Comment: OK then you could use Liquibase LoadData with different contexts. Liquibase ensures that data will be inserted only once as it saves the migration checksum in a table of your db schema.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou, the LoadData is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of these:

**Liquibase**

Using Liquibase with a changelog to insert data with the [loadData](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) tag (like jhipster inserts initial users). This changelog must be appended to the master.xml. Liquibase takes care of executing each changelog only once.

We did not use this one, because when the initial data changes, you will need another csv with a new changelog and this could be very confusing. Furthermore, you will need the data in a form that matches the form of the table. So, in turn it must be (more or less) static data.

**Application Listener**

So we use a "startup-hook", so we can already access the database and are able to dynamically define entities, calculating stuff etc.

For this, we hookup the application start event by implementing `implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` in a component, e.g.

```
@Component
public class StartupService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        //...loading stuff
    }
}
```

You will need something to check, if you already inserted the data or not. A simple one, would be to check if the repository is empty. We have somekind of an own migration-table for that, which is checked in the onApplicationEvent. This allows us to "register" different migration-steps to this startup-method.

Comment: Don't forget about using Liquibase contexts http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html it 's really helpful to load different data in test or in production.